# Oracle11g Database Synchornization

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, synchronization

I have a WPF application with back-end as Oracle11gR2. We need to enable our application to work in both online and offline(disconnected) mode. We are using Oracle standard edition(with single instance) as client database. I am using Sequnece Numbers for Primary Key Columns. Is there anyway to sync my client and server database without any issues in Sequence number columns. Please note that we will restrict creation of basic(master) data to be created only in server.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches to take here.

1- Write the sync process to rebuild the server tables (on the client) each time with a SELECT INTO.  Once complete, RENAME the current table to a "temp" table, and RENAME the newly created table with the proper name.  The sync process should DROP the temp table as one of its first steps.  Finally, recreate the indexes and you should be good-to-go.

2- Create a backup of the server-side database, write a shell script to copy it down and restore it on the client.

Each of these options will preserve your sequence numbers.  Which one you choose really depends on your skills.  If you're more of a developer, you can make #1 work.  If you've got some Oracle DBA skills you should be able to make #2 work.

Since you're on 11g, there might be a cleaner way to do this using Data Pump.

Comment: I am now doing the manula sync of data using my own logic using different range of(1-1 million in cleinet,>1 million in server)sequence numbers.But I was asked to look for the soultion provided by the Oracle 11g database. I am exploring about materialized views, Oralce Mobile server. Do you have any idea about these? Please note that there will atleast 2000 users for our application and 1000 of them may be use the database concurrently. So the soultion should be efficient and scalable.